# VueJS3, how to pass data from view01.vue to view02.vue

Tags: vuejs3

i want to pass a data from a view (.vue file) to another view (.vue file).

Not from a component to a view or from a view to a component.

here my view05.vue code

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import { toRefs } from 'vue';
import view06 from '../views/view06.vue'





const router = useRouter();

const enteredValue = ref('retest');

const state = reactive({
  enteredValue: 'test'
})

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/view06/:enteredValue',
    name: 'view06',
    component: view06,
    props: true,
  }
]

function checkIfNumbers() {
    if (/\d/.test(enteredValue.value)) {
        alert('enteredValue contains numbers!');
    } else {
        // router.push('/view06');
        // router.push({ name: 'view06', params: { enteredValue: enteredValue.value } });
        // router.push({ name: 'view06', params: toRefs(state) });
        
        router.push({ name: 'view06', state: {enteredValue} });
    }
}

</script>

<template>
    <main>
       <div section = "section01">
            <div class = "formulaire">
                <h1>Please Enter Your Login</h1>
                <form @submit.prevent="checkIfNumbers">
                    <label for="enteredValue">Enter your
                    value:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="enteredValue" v-model="state.enteredValue" />
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Check if Numbers</button>
                </form>
            </div>
       </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

And here my view06.vue file code

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from "vue";
import { toRefs } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const routeParams = computed(() => route.params);
//const enteredValue = toRefs(routeParams).enteredValue;
// const enteredValue = toRefs(routeParams).state;
const enteredValue = toRefs(routeParams).enteredValue;

</script>

<template>
    <main>
        <div section = "section01">
            <div class = "description">
                Controller de la view 06: Aucun
                <br>
                la valeur recue est: {{ enteredValue }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

FF console does not me render error, but nothing displayed.
Does anyone get advice or answer?

Thank you,
redrabbit

Comment: Shouldn't `router.push({ name: 'view06', state: {enteredValue} });` be, `router.push({ name: 'view06', params: {enteredValue} });`?

Comment: hi, no, it sends me error: [Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "enteredValue" when navigating. See https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22 for more details. And if i go over there, i read your syntax is deprecated, can break the app. they give example with state: state to save it to the History API state: but does not seem to work. So i do not know.